# Facing Issue "Cannot find class in classpath" in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am learning selenium, as part of i was trying to execute the below program. But i was getting the error " Cannot find class in classpath:practiseAutomation". The code is below:

```
public class practiseAutomation {
public WebDriver driver;
String baseurl="http://www.ticketnew.com/";
@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
System.out.println("Executing Before Test Block");  
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "c://IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get(baseurl);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
@Test
public void test()
{
System.out.println("Executing Test Block");   
System.out.println("The Page titile is "+ driver.getTitle());
}
}
@AfterTest
public void afterTest()
{
System.out.println("Executing After Test Block");
driver.close();
}
}
```

Kindly help me in resolving the above issue.

Comment: How are you invoking your test - resulting in the ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: Configured Testng and running it from Eclipse directly (Rightclick->Run as).

Comment: also, i m getting Null Pointer Exception @Test block.

Answer (score 0):

In your BeforeTest method, you are creating webdriver instance which has scope in beforeTest method only. It will throw null pointer in @Test and @AfterTest methods.

As you have already declared driver globally, so just initialize it in BeforeTest method like below:-

```
driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

and not `WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();`